# How to Configure Mixed Authentication in one page - Moss 2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, forms-authentication

Is it possible to have mixed authentication in one page(url)?
For eg: If a user may internal or external based on that AD authentication or Form authentication should validate the user. That is login page should be one. More in detail:

I have a situation where my company uses MOSS 2007 as a local intranet system. We have an Active Directory Server (ADS) and internally all users using MOSS apps are authenticated using Windows authentication.

We would now like to publish MOSS apps to the internet,and created Login page which would accept Username, Password and AD DomainName (which as of the moment, the user uses internally). Using Forms based authentication and ActiveDirectoryProvider, this page would then authenticate these parameters. So the login user may be internal or external users. Both type of users shoud be handled in one page.(The page is login.aspx which s having login webpart.)

Regards
Jhanani

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on exposing SharePoint to the outside and use FBA, I would recommend doing it through a proxy server, which can then hit your SharePoint farm. That's how we have deployed it for both internal Windows auth and external FBA.

We use [Microsoft's UAG](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/forefront/unified-access-gateway.aspx) to do so (and TMG for the proxying). Users are then AD-authenticated and can browse their allowed content on SharePoint from anywhere.

Any kind of reverse proxy is a good infrastructure practice when you're publishing internal resources to the world.

Makes sense?

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. Can you please share any site url which describes step by step process of what you have told, Because i dont have hands-on experience working in FBA.Pls help.

Regards
Jhanani

Comment: Here's [a decent link](http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=47). Do remember that it requires a good bit of infrastructure and systems deployment. At the end of the day, your first concern should be security, and proxying it back would be the best way to achieve it.